# uv-allign-distribute add-on

Tags: add-on

I have spent the last hour trying to install the uv-allign-distribute add on from revolution. I'm doing all the usual things that I've done with other add ons and nothing is happening. Im installing both from the zip file and also tried installing by opening the zip and trying to install each different .py script. Nothing, nadda, zero.

I ask for help because sometimes with a new version of blender apparently add ons behave differently, (windows create is now archimesh for example,) anyway, any help appreciated as usual.

Comment: A link to get the addon would help us find any problems with it.

Comment: a/uv-align-distribute

Comment: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?340206-Add-On-UV-Align-Distribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions for installing the addon could be clearer.

The [releases download page on github](https://github.com/c30ra/uv-align-distribute/releases) has several download options, the easy one is the `uv_align_distribute.zip` - download this and you can select the zip file after clicking *Install Add-on From File...* in blenders preferences.

[image: release download options]

If you download one of the other options or download the whole repo from the project page you get the whole repo and you will need to copy one folder out of it to your addon folder.

After unzipping the full repo download, copy the `uv_align_distribute` folder, into your addon folder, not the outer folder that will have `-master` or `-3.0` in the name, but the inner folder that will be seen with the `docs` and `tests` folders. The best location will be in `scripts/addons` in your [user config location](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/getting_started/installing/configuration/directories.html). If you want to, you could copy it into the blender install with the existing addons.

[image: correct folder to install]